# How can I write to a XCP parameter using Canoe .XCP and CAPL?

Tags: canoe

How can I write to an XCP parameter using Canoe .XCP and CAPL script?  We can measure these parameters but can not change them, is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CANoe creates a system variable for each .XCP parameter.

You setup the parameters in the XCP/CCP window.

In CAPL you can read and write the value of the parameters by accessing the corresponding system variables. Just check the symbol explorer. The system variables should all be in namespace `XCP`.

So changing the parameter `a0` of device `XcpSim` in CAPL would be something like

```
@XCP::XcpSim::a0 = 17;
```

*This example is taken directly from the CANoe documentation.*

Answer (score 0):

syntax: xcpActive(@XCP::XcpSim::a0)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).